# Designing CFG that accepts $a^n b^m c^p$ where $n=m+p+2$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free

I have generated the CFG of $a^n b^m c^p$ where $m = n+p+2$:

> $S \rightarrow ASC \mid \varepsilon$
>
> $A \rightarrow aAb \mid \varepsilon$
>
> $C \rightarrow bCc \mid \varepsilon$

I have been trying $a^n b^m c^p$ where $n=m+p+2$ but cannot figure out how to represent $n=m+p+2$.
Any hint would really be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that a language is context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free) You should look at examples.

Comment: I tried it myself and this was my solution
Is this correct?
S->abSA | a   , 
C -> Ac | NULL

Comment: No, because 1) $A$ is not rewritten 2) it can create $abaA$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I found the answer. Here it is:
$S->$C$S | aa  ,  $C->$A$C | NULL , $A->$B$A | a ,  B->a B b | NULL.  Please, do tell me if its correct. Thanks a lot

Comment: The grammar in your question recognises $a^nb^mc^p$ where $m = n + p$, not $m = n + p + 2$. Although it's easy to fix.